# How to plan length of a chapter?

Tags: formatting, chapters

I have planned my book to be around 250 pages. Because that is my target audience. In my country I can sell the book of that length for around 250-300 rupees. (*Its just my plan, I don't know yet how will it work out in reality). I have finished 80 pages which is the complete rough draft of my book. My ending is reached, now I am just going to fill in the blanks with major plots. Its still a meaningful writing.

How should I design length of a chapter. If I decide that each chapter should be around 20 pages then the story gets broken and shifted to next chapter. If I plan according to the story then one chapter has become 21 pages and another is 35 pages, which is extremely unsymmetrical. So my question is how and where to end the chapters?

Comment: We have a few questions about chapter lengths already: check [this one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/41/23927), [this one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/36349/23927), and [this one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/3225/23927), and let me know whether any of them address your concerns.

Comment: @F1Krazy that does answer my question. Most of the answers say it depends on the situation. If you say, you agree with one chapter 21 pages and another chapter 35 pages as my story flows. I can delete the question or mark as duplicate.

Comment: Mark it as a duplicate of whichever question helped you the most. That would be the most productive outcome, I think.

Comment: I'd retract my close vote, but I wouldn't be able to cast a second one for the correct duplicate. We'll have to wait for four other people to come along.

Comment: I marked as a duplicate of the "normal length for a chapter" question, so at least it is in there too.